# Test redux-saga delay amount using redux-saga-test-plan

Tags: redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

### Background

I have a "gradual-backoff" built into a saga using [Redux-saga's `delay()`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) effect.

I am using `expectSaga` from [redux-saga-test-plan](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/mocking/dynamic-providers.html) to write the test.

But in order [to get the test to work I had to disable the delay](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan/issues/182).

### Question

What is the best way to test the delay amount?

### Code

"Back off" function that returns 1s, 2s, or 3s

```js
const BACK_OFF_SERIES = [1000, 2000, 3000];
const backOff = attempt =>
  BACK_OFF_SERIES[Math.min(attempt, BACK_OFF_SERIES.length - 1)];
```

tryDownload saga

```js
const MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;
function* tryDownloadFiles(assets, downloadOptions) {
  for (let attempts = MAX_ATTEMPTS; attempts; attempts -= 1) {
    try {
      const urls = yield call(downloader, assets, downloadOptions);
      return urls;
    } catch (error) {
      if (attempts > 1) {
        yield call(delay, backOff(attempts));
      } else {
        yield put(
          showError({
            error: `${error}. Failed!`,
          })
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And an `expectSaga` test that uses a provider bypass the `delay`:

```js
const res = expectSaga(tryDownloadFiles, mockAssets, mockDownloadOptions)
  .provide([
    [matchers.call.fn(delay), null],
    [matchers.call.fn(downloader), throwError(mockError)],
  ])
  // .call(delay, backOff(3))
  // .call(delay, backOff(2))
  // .call(delay, backOff(1))
  .put(showError({ error: `${mockError}. Failed!` }))
  .run();
```

Comment: If you came up with a different solution please, let us know, otherwise accept my answer. Both could be useful for other users looking for the same answer 

Answer (score 0):

The [Dynamic Providers docs](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/integration-testing/mocking/dynamic-providers.html) you posted reports this example

```
.provide({
call(effect, next) {
// Check for the API call to return fake value
if (effect.fn === api.fetchUser) {
    const id = effect.args[0];
    return { id, name: 'John Doe' };
}

// Allow Redux Saga to handle other `call` effects
return next();
},
```

So, couldn't you push all the `effect.args` arguments (the delay amount) into an array and then check its content?